# boost accumulator_set: expect primary expression

Tags: c++, boost, boost-bind, boost-mpl, boost-accumulators

I am a new to Boost library. I want a program that could compute the min, max, mean and variance of a distance vector (of type `std::vector < double >`) and I wrote the following code

```
std::vector < double > dist_err;
// ... do something with dist_err
boost::accumulators::accumulator_set
< 
    double, 
    boost::accumulators::stats
    <
        boost::accumulators::tag::min , 
        boost::accumulators::tag::max ,
        boost::accumulators::tag::mean,
        boost::accumulators::tag::variance
    > 
> stat_acc;
std::for_each(dist_err.begin(), dist_err.end(), boost::bind < void > (boost::ref(stat_acc), boost::mpl::placeholders::_1));
std::cout << "min[distance error]: " << boost::accumulators::min      (stat_acc) << std::endl;
std::cout << "MAX[distance error]: " << boost::accumulators::max      (stat_acc) << std::endl;
std::cout << "  E[distance error]: " << boost::accumulators::mean     (stat_acc) << std::endl;
std::cout << "VAR[distance error]: " << boost::accumulators::variance (stat_acc) << std::endl;
```

But the program gives me an error at line `std::for_each(dist_err.begin(), dist_err.end(), boost::bind < void > (boost::ref(stat_acc), boost::mpl::placeholders::_1));` and it says

```
error: expected primary-expression before ')' token
std::for_each(dist_err.begin(), dist_err.end(), boost::bind < void > (boost::ref(stat_acc), boost::mpl::placeholders::_1));
```

Could someone please give me some hint on how to solve this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you are using `boost::mpl::placeholders::_1` inside code which doesn't use MPL.  Instead, just say `_1`.

Comment: Hi John, It works! Thank you so much for your reply. But I am still a little confused ... could you please try to explain where does that `_1` come from and what does it mean?

Comment: @BojianZheng: `_1` comes from Boost, though not in the `boost::` namespace.  It's also part of the C++11 standard which has `std::bind()`.  If you want to know what it means, just read the documentation.